# Browsers not recognising Content-Length header when using apache and cgi

Tags: apache, http, http-headers, cgi

For the first time I've had to wrap something I'm working on as a CGI script. I'm having trouble with browsers (Both both Chrome and Firefox) not recognising the Content-Length header and stating size "unknown" to the users.

[image]

When I test this with the linux too `wget`, the tool recognises the size just fine.

When I test this manually though `openssl s_client -connect` I get the following headers:

The precise output from the webserver is as follows:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Sun, 30 Jul 2017 20:12:20 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.25 (Ubuntu) mod_fcgid/2.3.9 OpenSSL/1.0.2g
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=foo.000000000G-000000001G.foofile.txt;
Content-Length: 501959790
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Content-Type: text/plain;charset=utf-8
```

Can anyone suggest what is missing / badly formatted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cracked it eventually.

This was caused by Apache doing something unexpected.  Apache is compressing the output of the CGI script on the fly (sending with `Content-Encoding: gzip`).  This changes the size of the file but Apache cannot know how much it is going to change when it sends the header.  The files are 1/GB each so it can't / doesn't cache the gzipped content before it starts sending therefore cannot know the file size.  This means it has to switch to `Transfer-Encoding: chunked`

One way to fix this is set `Content-Encoding: none` in the header which disables Apache from compressing the content.  This does mean that 1/2 GB files take much longer to send.

Another might be to manually gzip the content in my cgi script and setting `Content-Encoding: gzip` and `Content-Length: <gzipped size>`.  This will require me to work out the compressed size before sending.